# Надо вывести полученное через Entry число на новое окно Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Пишу маленькую программу для отсчета для времени. Но пока что хочу чтобы выводило введенное число в `Entry` в новое окно. Но выводит ошибку

```
import tkinter as tk
gui = tk.Tk(className="Timer")
gui.geometry("600x600")
label = tk.Label(text="Choose the time").pack()
entry = tk.Entry()
button = tk.Button(text="Click!")

def button_click(event):
    gui.destroy()
    guii = tk.Tk()
    guii.geometry("600x600")
    t = entry.get()
    labell = tk.Label(text=t)
    labell.pack()
    guii.mainloop()

button.bind("<Button-1>", button_click)
button.pack()
entry.pack()
gui.mainloop()
```

Comment: Ошибку добавьте в сам вопрос. Чтобы отредактировать вопрос, нажмите [edit] под ним.

Comment: во-первых, вы никуда ничего не выводите, во-2х, entry.get() когда entry уже нет - вы же уничтожили окно. Это как минимум

Answer (score 0):

Вы сначала уничтожили окно (вместе со всеми виджетами в нем), потом пытаетесь получить значение из уже не существующего entry. В данном случае можно просто получать значение до уничтожения окна:

```
def button_click(event):
    t = entry.get()  # Сначала получили значение
    gui.destroy()  # Потом уничтожили окно

    guii = tk.Tk()
    guii.geometry("600x600")
    labell = tk.Label(text=t)
    labell.pack()
    guii.mainloop()
```